# replace the null value to '-' in html table

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have the html table which I want to replace the empty date column with '-' in jquery.

```js
$("#table").find("td:2").html('<strong>not empty<strong/>')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <tr>
  <th>name</th>
  <th>age</th>
  <th>date</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>a</td>
  <td>12</td>
  <td>2021-04-01</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>b</td>
  <td>32</td>
  <td>invalid value</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

I have tried to replace the invalid value in all the date column to '-'

Comment: Your script does nothing due to there not being any table with the `id` **#table**

Comment: How did the data end up in the table in the first place? If the table is created on the server side, maybe it would be better to generate the right data at that point.

Comment: Blat the whole table?  `$("table").html($("table").html().replace(/invalid value/g, "-"))`

Comment: Question:  do you consider the string "invalid value" to be "empty"?  Doesn't look "empty" or "null value" to me.  Perhaps you could be clearer in your requirement and provide a valid example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why look for `<strong>not empty<strong/>` when your example table has `invalid value` ?

Also you do not have anything with id=table

Do you mean this?

```js
$("#table td").each(function() {
  if (this.textContent === "invalid value") this.textContent = "-"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>age</th>
      <th>date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="table">
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>2021-04-01</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>32</td>
      <td>invalid value</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.date').each(function(){
  if($(this).text()==''){
    $(this).text('-');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>age</th>
      <th>date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="table">
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td class='date'>2021-04-01</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>32</td>
      <td class='date'></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```